# Why can't I upload .htaccess file using terminal?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssi

I have a Amazon EC2 server running Apache, I'm trying to enable SSI using .htaccess file, I created the .htaccess file and saved it to my website files folder (not my server), and tried to upload it using `scp -i /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/jeffarries.pem /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/.htaccess ec2-user@ec2-54-213-219-247.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html` in Terminal, and got this error message:

> "/Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/.htaccess: No such file or directory"

How can I upload my .htaccess file to my Apache server using Terminal?

Thanks!

**Update:**
[image]
**Update 2:**
[image]

Comment: What does `ls -l /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/.htaccess` output? I would say this is not a question for [so] or [sf], but [su].

Comment: @muru Output `ls: /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/.htaccess: No such file or directory`

Comment: So you made a typo, or save the `.htaccess` file elsewhere.

Comment: @muru why would it matter where I stored it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant *saved*, not *save*. What is the output of `ls -Abl /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder`?

Comment: There you have it. The file is named `.htaccess.txt`, not `.htaccess`.

Comment: @muru AHA!  The sneaky .txt!  Uploaded it without a problem, thanks!  Do you want to post your comments as an answer and I can approve it?

Comment: Side note: Super User and Server Fault users have not responded or commented at all.

Comment: You should know cross-posting is strongly discouraged. Be thankful none of these posts have been downvoted or closed.

Comment: @muru Sorry! I wasn't sure what community to post it on!  I've removed the other posts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the output of `ls -Abl`, the filename is actually `.htaccess.txt`.

Side note:

- Enabling SSI for every `.html` file is a bad idea performance-wise. THe typical way is to use a special extension (like `.shtml`), or execute bits on the file (via `XBitHack`).
- On Apache 2.4, the current way is to enable [the `INCLUDES` filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) instead of using `AddHandler`:

  ```
  AddType text/html .html
  AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
  ```

  …
  `AddHandler server-parsed` is still supported for backward compatibility.